# split occurance of time from large string

Tags: python, string, split

in my task I want to fetch only time and store in variable, in my string it may be possible that time occurs more than 1 time and it may be "AM" or "PM"

I only want to store this value from my string.
"4:19:27" and "7:00:05" the occurrence of time may be more than twice.

```
str = """ 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ed820=Troubles | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405eec00=Some situations can be acknowledged using the 'OK' button, if present. A green check-mark after the description indicates that the situation has been acknowledged.  Some situations have further detail available by pressing on the text or icon of the trouble message. | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@407e5380=Zone Perl Thermostatyfu Communication Failure | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8=OK | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@4082ac98=Sep 12, 2017 4:19:27 AM | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40831690=Zone Door Tampered | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78=OK | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@407520c8=Sep 12, 2017 7:00:05 PM |  VIEW : -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ec8c0 | -1=android.widget.FrameLayout@405ed278 | 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ed820 | 16908290=android.widget.FrameLayout@405ee4d8 | -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ee998 | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405eec00 | -1=android.widget.ScrollView@405ef4f8 | 2131034164=android.widget.TableLayout@405f0200 | 2131034158=android.widget.TableRow@406616d8 | 2131034159=android.widget.ImageView@4066cec8 | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@407e5380 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8 | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@4082ac98 | 2131034158=android.widget.TableRow@4075e3c8 | 2131034159=android.widget.ImageView@4079bc80 | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40831690 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78 | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@407520c8 | -1=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405ec0c8 |  BUTTONS : 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78 | """
```

MY Code is

```
str = '''TEXT VIEW : 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ee2f0=Troubles | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405ef6d0=Some situations can be acknowledged using the 'OK' button, if present. A green check-mark after the description indicates that the situation has been acknowledged.  Some situations have further detail available by pressing on the text or icon of the trouble message. | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40630608=Zone Perl Thermostatyfu Communication Failure | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@40631068=OK | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@40632078=Sep 12, 2017 4:19:27 AM |  VIEW : -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ed390 | -1=android.widget.FrameLayout@405edd48 | 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ee2f0 | 16908290=android.widget.FrameLayout@405eefa8 | -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ef468 | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405ef6d0 | -1=android.widget.ScrollView@405effc8 | 2131034164=android.widget.TableLayout@405f0cd0 | 2131034158=android.widget.TableRow@4062f7a8 | 2131034159=android.widget.ImageView@4062fcd0 | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40630608 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@40631068 | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@40632078 | -1=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405ecb98 |  BUTTONS : 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@40631068 |'''

if " AM "  or " PM " in str: 
    Time = str.split(" AM " or " PM ")[0].rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
    print Time
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you shouldn't name a variable with a special word like `str`. You could use a regular expression, like this:

```
import re
my_string = """ 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ed820=Troubles | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405eec00=Some situations can be acknowledged using the 'OK' button, if present. A green check-mark after the description indicates that the situation has been acknowledged. Some situations have further detail available by pressing on the text or icon of the trouble message. | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@407e5380=Zone Perl Thermostatyfu Communication Failure | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8=OK | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@4082ac98=Sep 12, 2017 4:19:27 AM | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40831690=Zone Door Tampered | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78=OK | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@407520c8=Sep 12, 2017 7:00:05 PM | VIEW : -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ec8c0 | -1=android.widget.FrameLayout@405ed278 | 16908310=android.widget.TextView@405ed820 | 16908290=android.widget.FrameLayout@405ee4d8 | -1=android.widget.LinearLayout@405ee998 | 2131034163=android.widget.TextView@405eec00 | -1=android.widget.ScrollView@405ef4f8 | 2131034164=android.widget.TableLayout@405f0200 | 2131034158=android.widget.TableRow@406616d8 | 2131034159=android.widget.ImageView@4066cec8 | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@407e5380 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8 | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@4082ac98 | 2131034158=android.widget.TableRow@4075e3c8 | 2131034159=android.widget.ImageView@4079bc80 | 2131034160=android.widget.TextView@40831690 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78 | 2131034162=android.widget.TextView@407520c8 | -1=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405ec0c8 | BUTTONS : 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4081b4f8 | 2131034161=android.widget.RadioButton@4085bb78 | """
pattern = '\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M'
date_list = re.findall(pattern, my_string)
print(date_list)
# outputs ['4:19:27 AM', '7:00:05 PM']
```

Explanation of the pattern:

- \d{1,2} matches one or two digits
- : matches ":"
- \d{2} matches exactly two digits
- : matches ":"
- \d{2} matches exactly two digits
- \s matches a space
- [AP] matches either an A or a P, only one
- M, the last M

Comment: yup, my bad. just wanted to point `|` instead of `/`, @Toto thanks for correcting.

Comment: Just added it, now I'll remove it

Comment: I think I'll leave it be.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regex` with this expression: `([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) (AM|PM)`. This pattern will give you two groups: one for the numbers of the time and one for the `AM` or `PM` information. This is much better than splitting the string manually. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/TozH36/1), and get used to using `regex`.

All in all you can use it like this in `python`:

```
import re

p = re.compile('([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) (AM|PM)')
for (numbers, status) in p.match(theString):
    #prints the numbers like 04:02:55
    print(numbers)
    #prints the AM or PM
    print(status)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use `str` as a variable name because that's a builtin
so assuming your string is in `s`, here is an interactive demonstration of
what I think you want.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[=][^|=]+[AP]M [|]', s)
['=Sep 12, 2017 4:19:27 AM |', '=Sep 12, 2017 7:00:05 PM |']

>>> [r.split() for r in re.findall('[=][^|=]+[AP]M [|]', s)]
[['=Sep', '12,', '2017', '4:19:27', 'AM', '|'], ['=Sep', '12,', '2017', '7:00:05', 'PM', '|']]

>>> [r.split()[3] for r in re.findall('[=][^|=]+[AP]M [|]', s)]
['4:19:27', '7:00:05']

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/Kyqe/0.js"></script>
```

You can use this **regex**:

```
\d+:\d+:\d+
```

or `r'\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'`

Code: https://repl.it/Kyqe/0

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend here. For example:

```
import re

inputstring = '''...'''
timematch = re.compile('\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M')
print(timematch.findall(inputstring))
```

The regular expression in question matches any occurrence of XX:XX:XX AM and XX:XX:XX PM, and takes into account time noted as 4:00:00 AM as well as 04:00:00 AM.